# React native animation not working as intended

Tags: react-native

I have a problem and would like some help.
So I have multiple touchables or buttons when pressed moves itself down. I am using the same method to move all buttons and to differentiate which button is pressed I am using a state variable. Here is where the problem comes, if I press the first button it works as intended but when I press the 2nd button it only resets the position but doesn't move. Another thing that I found was that if I start doing it from last to the first button it works as intended.
I have posted my code. Any help is appreciated.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Animated,
  Easing,
} from 'react-native';

class Barakhari extends React.Component {



constructor() {
    super();
    this.animatedValue = new Animated.Value(0);
    this.state = {
      i: null
    };
  }

  drop(x) {
    console.log('b4 press:', this.state.i)
    this.animatedValue.setValue(0);
    this.setState({ i : x})
    Animated.timing(this.animatedValue, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 500,
      easing: Easing.ease
    }).start(() =>console.log('after press:', this.state.i));
  }

  render() {
    const top = this.animatedValue.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 1],
      outputRange: [0, 100]
    });
    return (
        <View
          style={{
            height: '100%',
            width: '100%',
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: 'red'
          }}
        >
          <View
            style={{
              height: '10%',
              width: '100%',
              borderWidth: 1,
              borderColor: 'white',
              flexDirection: 'row',
              alignItems: 'center',
              justifyContent: 'space-evenly'
            }}
          >
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.drop(1)}>
              <Animated.View
                style={{ top: this.state.i === 1 ? top : 0, height: 40, width: 40, backgroundColor: 'red' }}
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.drop(2)}>
              <Animated.View
                style={{ top: this.state.i === 2 ? top : 0, height: 40, width: 40, backgroundColor: 'green' }}
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.drop(3)}>
              <Animated.View
                style={{ top: this.state.i === 3 ? top : 0, height: 40, width: 40, backgroundColor: 'blue' }}
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
        );
      }
    }

export { Barakhari };
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Found one issue in code, might it'll help :)

`setState` function in `React` works in an asynchronous fashion, the state values are not immediately available after the update and  `React` re-render all components and sub components every time setState is called. If want to use updated value just after setting `state` then completion handler can be used

```
drop(x) {
    console.log('b4 press:', this.state.i)
    this.animatedValue.setValue(0);
    this.setState({ i : x},()=>{
        Animated.timing(this.animatedValue, {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 500,
        easing: Easing.ease
    }).start(() =>console.log('after press:', this.state.i));
})
```